# Third-party software questions

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

It seems Stack Overflow natively does not like any discussion related to third-party software.

In Super User, you can ask some specific things about the specific program, but Super User *prohibits* the following type of questions:

> ***Which software can do such thing?*** Let me know the lists. The
> more the better.

Is there a right Stack Exchange site to ask this kind of question?

For example: Which software can change color of titlebar in Windows 10? Is there a file explorer that shows size of file as bytes not mega or gigabytes?

Comment: Sounds like you want https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, the scale of that forum is small at present. That's a pity.

Comment: @imidak 1400 pages of questions and answers, not so small perhaps.

Comment: What is the source for the quote from Super User?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [the Software Recommendations site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (emphasis mine):

> **This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task**, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”. While this includes software libraries for development use, note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, media libraries (e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic – as are questions like “what technology to use for …?”

Make sure to search for your question there before asking so it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: And before posting there please read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 4):

"List" type questions are generally bad. No site does list type questions. I'd suggest that it might be possible to find what you need by rescoping a question to "how do I?" from "what are all the ways?"

From  the first example you gave in the comments.

"Which software can change color of titlebar in Windows 10?"

change that to "How do I change the colour of the titlebar in Windows 10?" and you get something [you can throw into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20do%20I%20change%20the%20colour%20of%20the%20titlebar%20in%20windows%2010) to get an answer.

While software recommendations *broadly* covers software recommendations it's not about generating long lists of software; [it is about finding *a* tool to solve a specific problem](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

From there, you can try a few alternatives and refine your question for either site.

Comment: Re *"No site does list type questions"*: MathOverflow has the tag [Big list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/big-list). Example: *[Video lectures of mathematics courses available online for free](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free)* with 80 answers.